# cause you to sleep late or affect your rest

Tags: american-english, spoken-english, sentence-usage

The situation is, I phone somebody in his evening and I feel sorry because it's late.

In my mother language, there's an expression like, "Sorry for causing you to sleep late" or "Sorry for affecting your rest". These sentences mean if I don't call he could go to bed early.

If I put the sentences directly into English, I think they sound weird. Is there a better way or native expression to say the same thing?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

> **Sorry to call so late**, but we really need those TPS reports.
>
> **Sorry for keeping you up**, the server went down and we need help getting it back up.
>
> Hi Alice, **I hope I didn't wake you**, but aliens are invading and we're having some trouble finding the instructions for the anti-alien ray gun.